# How to scroll an element to exactly the middle of a screen using Selenium with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, robotframework, screen

I'm automating a webpage using Robot Framework, Selenium and python. There are several clicks on different elements of the page, and I want to first scroll the element exactly to the middle of the screen, and then click on it.

I have already used this:

```
self.seleniumlibrary.scroll_element_into_view(element)
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything or at least scroll the element to the middle of the screen. Is there a JavaScript code I can use? I know that I can get the width and the height of the screen like this:

```
height, weight = self.seleniumlibrary.get_window_size()
```

but then what? I checked other questions/answered, but none of them were using Python.

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps you can take:

1. Try to maximize the browser screen with the command

> maximize browser window

2. Do a web page scroll

> execute javascript window.scrollTo(0,2500)

> 0 = start condition for scrolling page

> 2500 = how far to scroll the webpage

*or you can do* :

> scroll element into view (*element*/*xpath*)

hope can help you